# Getting start with Maven

Tags: maven-2

I am very new to Maven.I have installed the maven on my local machine.
After installation for trial basis i was trying to execute ***mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app***
for that i am getting below error message.

```
C:\work\maven2.2\bin>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache
.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retri
eved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: repo1.ma
ven.org
[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exi
st or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 30 11:45:49 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can any one help me if i need to have a prerequisite setting for the same?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's comand is correct and on my computer run correctly. But you have Error transferring file. So on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145896/what-could-be-causing-error-transferring-file-in-maven) branch you may read about this error.

**EDIT:**

Tutorials:
First of all read this article : [maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

For more information : [Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

The second article will give you all you need to understend maven.

Comment: is it causing me due to firewall or Proxy setting ?

Comment: As for me it's smth like that. It's may be this causes. But i sure that your line to create project is correct. So seach cause in connection seting. And try this code : mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

Comment: thanks for your support.. Last question could you point me to a simple example/tutorial for understanding of maven ?