# Maven Connection Reset error

Tags: maven

I have a maven project on linux.
It was building fine until last week.
Today I am getting below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-integration-service: Could not resolve
dependencies for project com.mycompany.myproj:my-integration-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies for [org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE
(compile), org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE (compile), ...]: No versions
available for joda-time:joda-time:jar:[2.2,) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

I checked my settings.xml , and in local repository I can see the many versions of this... library  2.2 , 2.4 ... 2.9.1

I also saw the file M2_REPO/joda-time/joda-time/resolver-status.properties

```
maven-metadata-codehaus.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus (http\://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus)\: Error transferring file\: repository.codehaus.org
...
maven-metadata-spring-milestone.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to spring-milestone (http\://maven.springframework.org/milestone)\: Error transferring file\: Connection reset
....
maven-metadata-com.springsource.repository.maven.releases.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to com.springsource.repository.maven.releases (http\://maven.springframework.org/release)\: Error transferring file\: Connection reset
...
maven-metadata-just-testing.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to just-testing (http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2)\: Access denied to\: http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/maven-metadata.xml
...
maven-metadata-apache.snapshots.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to apache.snapshots (http\://repository.apache.org/snapshots/)\: Error transferring file\: Connection reset
...
maven-metadata-maven-restlet.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata joda-time\:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-restlet (http\://maven.restlet.org)\: Error transferring file\: Connection reset
```

Also I ran command mvn -X archetype:generate as suggested [What could be causing 'error transferring file' in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145896/what-could-be-causing-error-transferring-file-in-maven)

```
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Connection reset
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        ....
        ....
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:658)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 31 more
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[DEBUG] Using catalog /wmchome/hfundadm/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype
```

Not very sure what could cause this error?

1. any port blocked? If so then why error in 1 file only ?
2. not sure if local_repository is being ignored ? it has needed file there
3. List item

Using Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500)

```
<profile>
      <id>defaultProfile</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://my-mvn-repo/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://my-mvn-repo/repo</url>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <properties>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
      </properties>
</profile>
```

but I don't see any server with `<id>` as central, there are many servers... not sure which one is being used

```
<server>
        <id>abccommon_id</id> 
        <username>abccommon_adm</username>
        <password>****</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Very important leave Maven 3.0.3 as soon as possible, cause it has many [bugs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12316922&version=12330178)...use newer versions..3.0.5, .3.1.1, 3.2.5 or 3.3.9....See http://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: thanks , taken a note of that

Answer (score 8):

I used the following flag and it downloaded everything successfully.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Someone has an explanation why this solves the issue?

Comment: explicit version of Transport Layer Security?!

Answer (score 1):

```
I had proxy issue
```

update V:\Ecomm\apache-maven-3.6.1\conf\settings.xml

```
sample:
```

```
  <proxies>
      <proxy>
          <id>example-proxy</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>proxy.example.com</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <username>proxyuser</username>
          <password>somepassword</password>
          <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to your repository.

```
Access denied to\: http\://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/maven-metadata.xml
```

...

The most likely issue here is your credentials. You probably didn't provide them correctly.

Comment: strange , it was working fine last week , let me rechek

Comment: i could access this link from my browser , will have to check which user the build script is using

Comment: Hi Geeth , as per the tutorial here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_repositories.htm , maven 1st searches in local repo , then central repo , last remote repo ... and in my case i can see the jar file present in local repo , and also central repo one with access denied error doesnt seem to have a password its open for all ( correct me if wrong )

Comment: but did you check your credentials?

Comment: Accessing via browser is something different than accessing with Maven...often browser have SSO mechanism and may be proxy accesses configured which you usually don't configured in Maven settings.xml file...

Comment: updated the ques , there are many server configured , didn't see any one configured as central .... unable to decide which one is being used ... as different teams seem to have put in entries there

Comment: Credentials to access public maven central repository?

Answer (score 0):

I had a proxy issue, too, and I already had a proxy set up. I was getting the Connection Reset error. This error appeared when trying to access a resource on my network.

I had to add a nonProxyHosts line like Bharath provided and this resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error while using any maven build commands. I realized it was happening due to the oracle jdk (19, 17, 11 etc) that I was using. I switched my jdk from oracle to an open-source one e.g OpenJDK, and this resolved the issue.