# Non-resolvable parent POM-Could not transfer artifact

Tags: java, rest

I am new Java developer.I tried to load the build after generating from spring intializer.Receiving the following error while trying to import maven project.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.example.restapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>dev.restapi.proj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dev.restapi.proj</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried Maven update , mvn clean install problem is not yet solved.

I tried mvn -U build as suggested

Error received is
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for dev.example.restapi:dev.restapi.proj:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.0.1.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10: Connection reset by peer ->

Comment: Please click the "?" at the top right of the edit box to see how to use Markdown to format your question properly.

Comment: Also: from the error message, it seems you had an earlier problem connecting to Maven Central. Perhaps try `mvn -U build` - the `-U` option will force an update so that it will re-attempt to connect instead of trying to use the cache.

Comment: I tried the command problem persist.Is there anything else that can be done to resolve this.Thanks. I have posted the error receieved

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" makes this sound like a networking issue and not a maven, pom.xml issue. Are you calling this command from a workplace computer or cloud provider?

Here is someone else with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170811/maven-connection-reset-error