# Some dependencies not getting downloaded by Maven even when using a proxy

Tags: java, maven

2 out of 14 dependencies are not getting downloaded even though I am already using a proxy.
Any other configuration in settings.xml needed specifically for these 3? So far engineers in my project has only given 1 proxy.

1. org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:7.3.2-ccs
2. io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:7.3.0

See error below:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Kafka-Testing: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jsmart:Kafka-Testing:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:7.3.2-ccs (absent), io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:7.3.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:7.3.2-ccs from/to confluent (http://packages.confluent.io/maven/): Connection
reset

Comment: That `Connection reset` looks like a network/firewall/proxy issue???

Comment: Would anything in [Maven Connection Reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34170811/3124333) help you?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your comments. Another engineer advised whitelisting to address these 2 errors. Will update this question once my request is processed.

Comment: As per our cloud architect, *.confluent.io is already whitelisted so it did not solve the issue. any other insights? that you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 issues that caused the problem.

1. there was an issue with proxy settings of the business.
2. maven repository in pom.xml is http. Since Maven 3.8.1, this is getting blocked.

Solutions:

1. change settings.xml proxy to use IP address instead of url
2. change maven repo url to "https://io.confluent..." to avoid blocking download of affected dependencies.