# Create new module using maven

Tags: maven-3, magnolia

I have tried to generate a module through Maven using:

```
C:\Dev>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

but gives me following exception:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: nexus.magnolia-cms.com
```

Comment: Run Maven with `-X` option to see details, i.e. `mvn -X archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/`

Comment: Still throws same exception.

Comment: Yes, it should throw the same exception, but you should see more details on what is Maven trying to do. The `-X` option makes Maven output verbose. Btw. I tried your command line on my machine and it has worked, so I suspect some problem in your network, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145896/what-could-be-causing-error-transferring-file-in-maven

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-358

Try to reconfigure your repo or use attached patch for maven plugin to work around the problem.